# 3 fingers drag and drop

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, gestures, touchegg

Using 16.04 with Unity I have a touchpad and I'd really like not to have to hold a button while I select text or drag & drop something nor the fake double click before dragging, I never found that handy.
I was able to configure this ["three finger drag"](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204609) feature on a Macbook quite easily and really enjoyed it.

I tried to configure it with [touchegg](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg) but it does not work with Ubuntu 16 and with [libinput-gestures](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures) but it does not manage the drag & drop.

All I need is to simulate a click while I have 3 fingers down until I release them.

Does someone know how I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I might have an idea.

You could try installing Fusuma, there is an explanation on how to install it on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036165/how-to-map-three-finger-swipe-up-to-view-all-open-windows/1054132).

It allows you to do custom commands for things like swipe and pinch. You might be able to configure it someway to do it with clicks? Or check the [GitHub](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma) for a how to do it.

Hope it helps.