# How to map three finger swipe up to view all open windows

Tags: 18.04, gestures, mousepad

Im using Ubuntu 18 with Gnome and I had configured a three finger swipe up to Show Windows Overview with my previous version with Unity but Im unable to do it here.

Ive installed easyStroke but that doesnt seem to have such a feature. What elese can I do to achieve this.

Comment: Duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034624/touchpad-gestures-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Touchpad Gestures in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034624/touchpad-gestures-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/a/1044184/846886

The solution using **fusuma** works well (answered above).

First add yourself to the "input" group and **log out/log back in**:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
```

Install all **pre-requisite** packages:

```
sudo apt install libinput-tools xdotool ruby
```

Install **fusuma** gem:

```
sudo gem install fusuma
```

Create a **configuration file** as your user:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/fusuma
gedit ~/.config/fusuma/config.yml
```

Paste the following as an **example config**:

```
swipe:
  3: 
    left: 
      command: 'xdotool key alt+Left'
    right: 
      command: 'xdotool key alt+Right'
    up: 
      command: 'xdotool key super+s'
    down: 
      command: 'xdotool key super+l'
  4:
    left: 
      command: 'xdotool key super+Left'
    right: 
      command: 'xdotool key super+Right'
    up: 
      command: 'xdotool key super+a'
    down: 
      command: 'xdotool key super+s'
pinch:
  in:
    command: 'xdotool key ctrl+plus'
  out:
    command: 'xdotool key ctrl+minus'

threshold:
  swipe: 1
  pinch: 1

interval:
  swipe: 1
  pinch: 1
```

Enable fusuma to **start automatically**:

[fusuma auto start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRm7E.png)

More at the [fusuma github page](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma)

Answer (score 0):

Two issues - i was running with sudo, so I guess the user config file was not being read. Running without sudo with the following config does what I want:

```
swipe:
  3:
    left:
      command: 'xdotool key alt+Left'
    right:
      command: 'xdotool key alt+Right'
    up:
      command: 'xdotool key super+s'
    down:
      command: 'xdotool key super+s'
  4:
    left:
      command: 'xdotool key super+Left'
    right:
      command: 'xdotool key super+Right'
    up:
      command: 'xdotool key super+s'
    down:
      command: 'xdotool key super+l'
pinch:
  in:
    command: 'xdotool key ctrl+plus'
  out:
    command: 'xdotool key ctrl+minus'

threshold:
  swipe: 1
  pinch: 1

interval:
  swipe: 1
  pinch: 1
```