# Are there settings in Ubuntu 20.04 similar to multiple figure gesture controls in Windows?

Tags: windows, touchpad, 20.04, multi-touch, personalization

Are there settings in Ubuntu 20.04 similar to multiple figure gesture controls in Windows? If there are how do I activate and configure them? At least, is there an extension that can do this? See images below to what windows offer. Also is there a way to add refresh (`alt` + `F2`) to the right-click menu?

[image: 3 fingure]
[image]

**Edit:** I have tried [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ci6YbQGx3c4&frags=pl%2Cwn) but it didn't work for me. I found a good solution with [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1253/extended-gestures/) which is exactly what I want but it only works for Wayland. Is there anyonewho can give me an alternative or create one for me?

Comment: I have tried https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ci6YbQGx3c4&frags=pl%2Cwn but it doesn't work well...

Comment: The issue with Ubuntu is that when you press Alt-Tab, it only switches back to the previous tab, whereas, in Windows, it would keep the tab switcher open and allow you to change the apps as long as the fingers are on the touchpad. I've been trying to configure that functionality on Ubuntu as well, but haven't managed so far.

Comment: @AbhigyanChattopadhyay You sure? It cycles all the way for me ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using fusama? https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma

It has very nice calibration options to change the sensitivity so it might be an improvement to vanilla libinput-gestures.

Comment: Will try that and let you know...

Comment: Almost works. For some reason, swipe left and right with e figures doesn't work. Can you tell me why? https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ryQXbzy7qD/ 
Also, there seems to be a syntax error in the last few lines. Can you tell me what is wrong? If you can help here I will accept your answer...

Comment: Glad I could help. Check for indentation errors in line 26, 27 and 32

Comment: That did not solve the issue. As you can see, the values of threshold are not recognized. Also, the swipe action is recognized and shown in the terminal when I run fusuma there. However, the 3 figure swipe left and right actions are not performed. What I want to do is switch windows by this action similar to what Windows 10 does. Can you tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error now, as my ubuntu is out of work. File an issue on github if you need further assistence with the software as I am not a developer of it. If my answer solved you question, please feel free to accept it.

Comment: Yes I will. Thanks @JoJota

Comment: But please try to help me solve this issue too. As the 3 finger windows swap is the gesture that I use most.

Comment: I have never used github. How do you file an issue there?

Comment: I see you have found your way to the issue. Maybe try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036165/how-to-map-three-finger-swipe-up-to-view-all-open-windows or  this https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma/issues/101 to further investigate your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to use touchegg. It allows you to add your own custom gestures to accomplish very much what you are looking for.

This guide is pretty good on setting it up: https://www.maketecheasier.com/add-multitouch-gestures-ubuntu/

Comment: It says error loading /home/username/.xprofile when I try to log in. It lists all the things in the file and says commands not found. It also says this session is not configured properly and to fix it asap.